# SQL Server BCP Empty File

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to use `bcp` to query out a comma-separated-value file but each time I get an empty file.

Here's my `bcp` command:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM ##OutAK "  QUERYOUT D:\Outbound\raw\li14090413.raw -c -T -t -S DB1
```

I have verified that `##OutAK` is NOT empty because `select count (*) from ##OutAK` is not 0. When open file using HEX editor, I see the following:

```
0D 0A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems BCP is "allergic" with NULL. So, I just put ISNULL() to all the null-able fields and the output file is back to normal now.